# path exception for image css max-width

Tags: css

at the moment I have some simple css code that sets images within blogs to a set size in order to be mobile friendly.

```css
.BlogContent img {
    max-width:80px;
    max-height:80px;
}
```

I have encountered an issue where emoticons end up be forced up to that size as well, because it is an image inside of the blog content, so they are being forced from 16px up to 80px and looks rather comical.

So, perhaps this is a horrific way of going about this, but I thought... 'hmm, maybe if I can define a path variable exception for emoticons that would work?'.

Does anybody know of a way in which to not apply this forced-photograph-size for files that have a specific root uri?

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/media/blogimage.png -- does get resized

http://www.example.com/emoticons/mrgreen.png -- does NOT get resized
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this entirely with CSS by using the [`*=` attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) to match part of your image's URL, combined with the [negation pseudo-class (`not()`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

```css
.BlogContent img:not([src*="/emoticons/"]) {
    max-width:80px;
    max-height:80px;
}
```

This will apply the `max-width` and `min-width` to any `img` descendant of an element with the `.BlogContent` class whose `src` attribute does not contain "/emoticons/".